# iPhone OpenGL : Adding a background image

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, uiimageview

Right so I got all my lovely openGL stuff working and I can change the background colour via the property of the view or even the window however for the love of god I cant change it to an image.

- I have tried adding it to the nib
- I have tried adding a UIImageView as 
  a subview.
- I have tried addiing it as a UIColor 
  with Pattern
- I tried making the OpenGL view have a
  clear background and setting the
  image on the actual window.

Still no joy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue a glClear then render 2 triangles (ie a quad) to the screen with the appropriate image texture mapped onto them.

Comment: I thought the texture has to be square where as my image is a rect

Comment: Don't worry, your screen won't become bigger if you use a 512x512 image instead of an 320x480 ;)

Comment: Apparently the iPhone supports non power of two textures in a limited set of cases that might just suit your needs :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760174/rendering-to-non-power-of-two-texture-on-iphone