# Rendering to non-power-of-two texture on iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, render-to-texture

Is it possible to render to texture with OpenGL ES 1.1 on the iPhone (2G and older)? If I bind a texture as a render buffer, it has to be the size of the render buffer, which isn't POT-sized. But OpenGL ES 1.1 requires textures to be POT.

Maybe it can't be done on ES 1.1?

Answer (score 27):

While OpenGL ES 1.1 does not support non-power-of-two textures, newer iOS device models have the extension [`GL_APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/APPLE/APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot.txt), which states:

> Conventional OpenGL ES 1.X texturing
>   is limited to images with power-of-two
>   (POT) dimensions. 
>   APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot
>   extension  relaxes these size
>   restrictions for 2D textures.  The
>   restrictions remain in place for cube
>   map and 3D textures, if supported.
>
> There is no additional procedural or
>   enumerant API introduced by this
>   extension except that an
>   implementation which exports the
>   extension string will allow an
>   application to pass in 2D texture
>   dimensions that may or may not be a
>   power of two.
>
> In the absence of OES_texture_npot,
>   which lifts these restrictions,
>   neither mipmapping nor wrap modes
>   other than CLAMP_TO_EDGE are supported
>   in  conjunction with NPOT 2D textures.
>   A NPOT 2D texture with a wrap mode
>   that is not CLAMP_TO_EDGE or a
>   minfilter that is not NEAREST or
>   LINEAR is  considered incomplete.  If
>   such a texture is bound to a texture
>   unit, it is  as if texture mapping
>   were disabled for that texture unit.

You can use the following code to determine if this extension is supported on your device (drawn from Philip Rideout's excellent [iPhone 3D Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596804822) book):

```
const char* extensions = (char*) glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS); 
bool npot = strstr(extensions, "GL_APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot") != 0;
```

On these devices, you should then be able to use non-power-of-two textures as long as you set the proper texture wrapping:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Unfortunately, [this example application](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ColorTracking.zip) that I have which renders to a non-power-of-two texture uses OpenGL ES 2.0, so I'm not sure that will help you in this case.

Comment: You should *not* use *strstr* to check for the extension name in the extension string. This does not ensure you that another extension starting with the same prefix may not be misinterpreted. Say check for *GL_ARB_shadow* with strstr will bite you if you have *GL_ARB_shadow_ambient*. I've been bitten once a long time ago when a software update brought a new GL extension in the driver, and broke my code months after its release.

Comment: @rotoglup - That's a great point.  As I said, this was code drawn from Philip Rideout's book.  Perhaps you might write him something for the errata on the book.

Comment: Thanks @rotoglup, I'm adding this to my book's errata.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, all you need to do is get the next power of 2 bigger than the non-POT.

Then generate a framebuffer:

```
GLuint aFramebuffer;
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &aFramebuffer);
```

And a texture:

```
GLuint aTexturebuffer;
glGenTextures(1, &aTexturebuffer);
```

Then you do the same texture like things:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, aTexturebuffer);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glColor4ub(0, 0, 0, 255);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, textureWidth, textureHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

int area[] = {0.0, 0.0, renderWidth, renderHeight};

glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, area);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, aFramebuffer);
glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_TEXTURE_2D, aTexturebuffer, 0);
```

Here I used the draw_texture extension.
`textureWidth` and `textureHeight` are the power of 2 bigger, and `renderWidth` and `renderHeight` are the the rendere's width and height.
Then when you bind to `aFramebuffer` it will draw to texture.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. glCheckFramebufferStatusOES returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS.

Comment: @Kronikarz: Did you create a renderbuffer also? As in `glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RGBA8_OES, width, height);` to connect to the framebuffer?

Comment: @Kronikarz: In my experience, you should also be able to render to a non-POT texture as well without rounding up the sizes, I believe.

Comment: @quixoto: That may be so, but I won't be able to display such a texture, I don't think.

Comment: @quixoto: I created the renderbuffer and connected it.

Comment: @Kronikarz: To be clear, iPhone definitely supports non-POT textures under GL 1.1 under very specific conditions. (I use them all the time.) The tech note is here: http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/APPLE/APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot.txt I can't find the iOS doc the references it. Your tex params must conform to certain limitations.

Comment: How odd. I got the code out of O'Reilly's iPhone 3d Programming book, and works on my end.
@quixoto I knew there was an extension, but I always thought it was for OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: @quixoto: This extension is not available on the iPhone versions I have, unfortunately.

Comment: @Kronikarz: Ah, you're way back on the 2G or whatever. You should clarify this in your question so people know you're asking about legacy (frankly) platform stuff. Good luck!