# iOS OpenGL ES - Render screen to FBO on application resign for redraw later

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I want to render my screen to a texture so that I can just "paste" the texture onto the screen when I come back into the application again. 
Currently in my app I am drawing a waveform with kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking set to TRUE. It works, but the screen is cleared after I resign from my app and come back again. Is this normal behaviour with kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking TRUE? 
I cannot afford the fps to redraw everything again when i come back to my application.

I've already stumbled upon this : [How to save and redraw screen content in OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985962/how-to-save-and-redraw-screen-content-in-opengl-es) and am trying to apply the answer to my needs, but I'm still having problems.

With reference to the answer from the other question, here's how I tried to do it.

```
@property (nonatomic) GLuint framebuffer;
@property (nonatomic) GLuint texture;
```

The code on loading in the glkviewcontroller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillResignActive) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillTerminate) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &_framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, _framebuffer);


    glGenTextures(1, &_texture);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 768, 1024, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
.....
```

When this viewController is notified that the app is resigning I use this function :

```
 -(void)appWillResignActive
{
    glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture, 0);
    if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
        NSLog(@"Error!");
}
```

I'm getting error still after checking the status above. 
What could be the issue here? I'm pretty new to OpenGL ES, pardon me if this is a newbie question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I was trying to the texture and framebuffer binding above before the context initialization.

```
    // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context and provide it to the
    // view
    view.context = [[AGLKContext alloc]
                    initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    view.delegate = self;

   // Make the new context current
   [AGLKContext setCurrentContext:view.context];
```

Putting the code after this allows the check to go through.