# IOS open GL ES drawing cube

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es

I'm creating an iPad application which uses Open GL ES 1.1 to draw a textured cube. I'm an Open GL newbie, so maybe this questions will be stupid, but:

- what is the maximum/preferred size of cube faces on iPad? I'm using 1024x1024 size, and in simulator everything works fine, but on device in 80% cases I get memory warning and crash. But when it loads first time, I can change cube faces without problems.
- does cube faces size have to be a multiply of 2 (256, 512, 1024 etc) - I'm asking because when I load for example 750x750 face, I have a strange rendering, and I don't know if I have to change somethong in code, or it's a limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i figured everything out, and if someone is curious:

1. memory warning and crashes was caused by strange behaviour which was described [Here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1747621?start=0&tstart=0) and it was solved exactly as suggested
2. textures size has to be power of 2

So topic is closed.

Comment: Actually, your second point is incorrect.  The iPad supports non-power-of-two textures through the `GL_APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot` extension.  See my answer here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760174/rendering-to-non-power-of-two-texture-on-iphone/4761453#4761453

Comment: @Brad It's slightly correct - if using a compressed texture, the texture size _must_ be a power of two.  I don't know which he's using, but if he had issues loading a NPOT texture, that might be what that particular problem was.

Comment: @nil - Yes, that's why it's a limited NPOT extension (there are also restrictions on clamping, etc.).  I just wanted to point out that the textures don't *have* to be powers of 2 on the iPad.