# OpenGL ES won't delete my texture in memory

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, memory-leaks, textures

I'm currently developing an iOS application (iPad and iPhone) that uses OpenGL ES 1.0 to render some basic textures. I use atlases to store and present my textures.

My main atlas is relatively large (2000x2000) but my internal algorithms load and resize the texture to 2048x2048 since OpenGL ES only accepts power of 2 sized textures. I'm able to draw the tiles, everything's fine on this side.

I'm facing a serious memory leak every time I try to load and unload (destroy) the texture. This should happen in the final version but I needed to make sure that my loading and unloading were fine. In memory the texture occupies 2048x2048x4 (RGBA) bytes = 16MB approx.
This is a huge amount of bytes so you understand that the problem is pretty annoying to me (iOS kills the application after a few minutes..)

When I load a texture, Instruments indicates that the overall memory used by the application increases by 16MB this is correct (I use the "Real Memory" column). The problem occurs when I need to destroy the texture to free all the possible bytes used by it: it never looses the 16MB...and since I load and unload in a loop, the memory keeps being used and never freed.

Here's how I load the textures:

```
GLubyte *outData = malloc((_dataWidth * _dataHeight * 4) * sizeof(*outData));
GLuint _texture; // declared as un instance variable so its address never changes
glGenTextures(1, &_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, _dataWidth, _dataHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, outData);
free(outData);
```

Here's how I unload the texture (this is called, I checked)

```
glDeleteTextures(1, &_texture);
```

I used glGetError() everywhere to check if an error occurs but it always returns 0 (even after  the glDeleteTexture).

Does anybody have an idea?
Thank you!

Comment: As a side note, every iOS device from the iPhone 3G S and newer should support non-power-of-two textures in OpenGL ES 1.1: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4761453/19679 . Also, have you thought about converting your atlas to use PowerVR Texture Compression (PVRTC)? Textures compressed in that manner are actually stored in memory in their compressed form, which can make their footprint much, much smaller than uncompressed textures. It won't solve your leak, but it might be a good idea in general.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure that you destroy your texture on the same thread, where you've created your context. If you're doing any GL calls without context there would be no errors.

Comment: Max, this answer helped me track down a really nasty texture leak in Core Image (because a CIContext was being shared across a thread boundary.) Thanks so much for this short, but very helpful, post!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `GL_APPLE_client_storage` extension? It means that instead of having OpenGL having a copy of the texture memory you promise to keep the data block passed to `glTexImage2D` alive until `glDeleteTextures` has been called.

Comment: Yeah, I think that extension is only for the Mac. On iOS 5.0, we can use something similar in the texture caches, but that's not what appears to be the case here.