# How to check if OpenGL ES implementation supports non-POT textures?

Tags: android, opengl-es

How to check, programmatically, if a given OpenGL ES implementation supports non-POT textures?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4761453/988027) answer your question?

Comment: @Dan Thanks! It gave me the right direction to look into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, what worked for me on Android was:

```
static public boolean isNPOTSupported(GL10 gl) {

    String extensions = gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS);
    return extensions.indexOf("GL_OES_texture_npot") != -1;
}
```

Comment: Do you know if the graphics driver / chip internally converts the texture to a power of 2? Or is it really possible with that extension to have some "odd" resolutions in order to save memory and bandwidth?