# Implementing non-power-of-2 textures in iSGL3d

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, isgl3d

I've written an app that relies heavily on iSGL3d for 3D rendering, and I've come to a point now where I need to start fiddling with texture sizes for memory allocation reasons.

My app uses very large textures (1024x1024) and going from that to 512x512 is unacceptable

So, using GL ES 2.0 as a basis, I want to slightly reduce my textures to something closer to 700x700

I know this is possible, because I've painstakingly handwritten OpenGL code in a previous life that uses non-power-of-2 textures

But I've had a hell of a time trying to sift through iSGL3d's code to find where I can affect this change... and the project appears to be abandoned now.

Basically, by default, even if you use a GLES 2.0 instance, iSGL3d will just make a power-of-two bitmap and dump your texture into it, leaving a bunch of transparent pixels. This is worthless.

Forcing the texture size to a non-power-of-two image generates GL errors. I am assuming this is because I am not properly forcing it everywhere it needs to be forced, or iSGL3d isn't properly using GLES 2.0 as it should be

Any pointers at all would be useful...

Comment: It does work on 2D textures. The only question is how to modify Isgl3D to behave with it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760174/rendering-to-non-power-of-two-texture-on-iphone

Comment: The cocos2d-iphone dev recently dealt with a huge mess of NPOT related issues in GLES 2.0 on iOS, here's a link to some discussion: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/31092 ... cocos2d is open-source, so maybe that would give you a starting place. Sorry, I know its not giving you any direction with Isgl3d, but maybe it'll help.

Comment: Update: I've been able to successfully bind the textures with Isgl3D without generating GL errors, however it requires that I disable mipmapping, which Isgl3D apparently relies on... because simply by disabling mipmapping, even valid textures fail to draw. Currently researching this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> simply by disabling mipmapping, even valid textures fail to draw

Did you set the minification sampling for these textures to not use the mipmaps? It defaults to mipmap option, so you have to set it to something else if you don't use mipmaps.

e.g.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Comment: This was very helpful thanks. iSGL for some reason does the first line, but not the second line (instead using mipmapping for min filter) even if you specify no mipmapping. Overriding the default flags enables the textures.